# No sound from some YouTube videos, sound mixer shows Firefox playing ok

Tags: windows-7, firefox, audio, audio-output

I got this weird sound issue on Firefox, which I've noticed on a lot of YouTube videos.
Normally this happens in sound mixer:

[image]

But then, when navigating to another YouTube video this happens:

[image]

I didn't change any setting or anything – I'm confused. I should also mention that besides my main output source there is a USB headset output... if this has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: Well, is there sound coming out of the USB headset?

Comment: nope, no sound output at all

Comment: sometimes adobe flash player is missing from the sound mixer...  so i restarted ff having my speakers as a default audio output and it seems to work... tried a couple of videos that were not working before and they work ok...
so maybe it has to do with html5/flv type of videos?
anyway i will test more and report back if it is still broken or if it's corrected.

Comment: I never have `Adobe Flash Player` in there at all. On another note, do you have the same issue if you remove the USB headset? Flash vs. HTML5 *should* not make a difference.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of Flash ?

Comment: i do, and that might be the problem as this issue started randomly... probably after a flash update?  
i notice adobe player appearing some times, on some youtube videos, if i restart firefox it goes away... if it's not that, what is it there for then?

Comment: March 2017 here; just saw this issue on current Firefox. (52.0.2, Win7, 32 bit).   FF restart worked though.    Same thing: audio from FireFox driving the VU meter in the volume mixer, but not heard.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning the volume down a bit on the YouTube video ***from within the YouTube player*** (it's weird, I know, but it worked for me).

I was having the same problem - Sound worked fine for some youtube videos but not others - the sound on some videos was nonexistent or I would just hear quiet pops and crackles.

I updated Flash, disabled my old flash plugin in Firefox (tools->addons->plugins) and restarted Firefox to no avail.

Then, I turned the volume down ***within the YouTube player*** and I could hear the sound properly. I think that on some of those videos, they try altering the sound track to make them louder and it causes a glitch where the sound won't play... That's my best guess as to why this worked for me.

Good luck!